# Using NUM/CAPS/SCROLL LOCK as RegisterHotKey Modifier in WinAPI

Tags: winapi, state, hotkeys, num-lock

I have the very well-known WinAPI function:

```
BOOL WINAPI RegisterHotKey(
  __in_opt  HWND hWnd,
  __in      int id,
  __in      UINT fsModifiers,
  __in      UINT vk
);
```

I see that I supposedly can only use the `MOD_ALT`, `MOD_CONTROL`, `MOD_SHIFT`, `MOD_WIN` keys, as well as `MOD_NOREPEAT`.

So I can use the following to create a **system-wide** hotkey for, say, the **A** key for the `Shift+A` combination:

```
RegisterHotKey(NULL,1,MOD_SHIFT,0x41);
```

---

***Now the important question:***

How can I use the state of either the NUM LOCK / SCROLL LOCK / CAPS LOCK (just like `MOD_SHIFT` and the other ones) as modifiers of a **system-wide** hotkey that I shall register, such that the registered key for the key combination behaves as a hotkey when any of such "LOCK" keys are turned on, and also behaves as a normal, non-trapped key when either of the "LOCK" keys are turned off?

I think that a timer and monitoring with something like `GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK)&0xFFFF` to register/unregister hotkeys would be too sloppy of a solution, maybe would slow down or interfere with the system performance, and it sounds like an incomplete way to proceed since it has to do with system-wide key behavior.

What better ways are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the situation I would probably just check for the state of a "LOCK" key at the beginning of your event code.

Otherwise if you really wanted to you can use [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a keyboard hook to do your monitoring.

Comment: The `SwtWindowsHookEx` function seems interesting. However, I think that just checking the state of the LED-LOCK keys is not enough because once a key is registered as hotkey, its normal behavior won't return **system-wide** unless it's unregistered as hotkey. I will double check further details about it to see what more can be done about that.